# How to add extra information to a custom PSObject property

Tags: powershell

Based on an export file and some checks I'm creating an array using the following block of code:

```
$Result += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            FQDN = $($Server.FQDN)
            IP = $($Server.IP)
            Description = $($Server.Description)
            Remarks = $("")
}
```

When I reuse this $Result, for another check, how can I add extra information in the "Remarks" property?

```
If ($Result.IP.Contains($IP.number)){

        $Result.Remarks += "Attention for this server" | Where-Object $Result.IP -eq $IP.number

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through the `$Result` array and modify the specific element with the correct `IP` value:

```
# Loop through array
$Result = foreach($object in $Result)
{
    # Check if array element is interesting
    if($object.IP -eq $IP.Number)
    {
        # Modify the  object in question
        $object.Remarks += "Attention!"
    }
    # Write the (potentially modified) object back to the array
    $object
}
```